# Regex in Android parsing error

Tags: android, regex, match

I have written a regex for extracting HTML a tag which has a class with name "c".
My regex expression is:

```
<div class=\"c\"(.*?)\<\/div\>
```

I have a huge HTML but the div which I want to extract is:

```
<div class="c">
    <a name="Adil Arif Bawany" href="/adil.arif.bawany?refid=5">
    </a>
    </br>
    <a href="tel:3222054008">Call</a>

</div>
```

This should work but but when I find out if there are any matches then boolean gives me false.

My code is:

```
String matchpa = "<div class=\\\"c\\\"(.*?)\\<\\/div\\>";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(matchpa);
Matcher m = patt.matcher(html);

boolean matchFound = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String matchpa = "<div class=\"c\"(.|\n|\r)*</div>";
```

It seems to match.

By the way, [this tool](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/) is very useful when dealing with reg exp.

Hope it helps

Jokahero

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find this useful: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/multiline.shtml. The problem is that your pattern will have to match multiple lines